# why doesn't iozone generate output file?

Tags: linux, excel, testing, io, filesystems

I'm using iozone3 for tesing, on Xamin (an Debian-based OS (xamin.ir/en/)).
 When I enter `iozone` command, for example `iozone -Rab output.xls`, [test runs successfully](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8135681892/Selection_030.png).

But after running the test (after displaying this message: `iozone test complete.`),instead of generating excel file, iozone returns the results [in shell](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8135676768/Selection_029.png).

Why doeasn't it generate excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should `$touch output.xls` the file first maybe the file does not exist :)